# Spacy v2 alpha - Can't find factory for 'TokenVectorEncoder'

Tags: spacy

I have trained a model, based off `spacy.blank('en')` and used `nlp.to_disk` to save it, however when I come to do `spacy.load('path/to/model')` I hit the error `Can't find factory for 'TokenVectorEncoder'`

Inside the model folder, there's a TokenVectorEncoder dir, and the meta.json file mentioned TokenVectorEncoder too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the model with the same spaCy alpha version you used for training? It looks like this error might be related to a change in the very latest `v2.0.0a17`, which doesn't use the `"tensorizer"`, i.e. `TokenVectorEncoder` in the model pipeline anymore. So the easiest solution would probably be to re-train your model with the latest version and then re-package and load it with the same version you used for training.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ines, and the Prodigy invite. I'm basing my model off 'en', loading with spacy.blank('en'), then I train. Upon saving, and then immediately loading afterwards with nlp.to_disk(output_dir), spacy.load(output_dir), I hit the error, and I'm using v2.0.0a17